How to parse transactions swap like explorers do
I'm trying to identify a buy or sell transaction, from which token to which token and how much was bought/sell.
My goal is to have an output similar to that of dexscreener, photon or gmgn...

I don't understand how they can parse a transaction in a universal way, I have the feeling I'd have to code a parser for each existing contract, which isn't feasible.
Currently, i use a logsubscribe and some poor logic using instructions or preTokenBalances and postTokenBalances, but it doesn't work for all cases.
Does anyone have any clues?
Thanks a lot!

They are likely using the program's Anchor IDL to generate a client that can decode instructions, or they integrate with various program libraries to parse any transaction.
